# import date from DE to Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, unsubscriber

I'm creating a preference page and I'm using a DE to populate my page and save the data, however I need to give the opportunity to unsubscribe and because off this I need to update the Subscribers with this information too.

There is some way to update Subscribers when something is updated in a DE?

Comment: Is the preference page hosted on a Cloudpage?

Comment: Hi Gortonington, yes it is. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple if it is hosted on Cloud pages, you can use either AMPScript API or SSJS to unsub the person at the same time as you update the DE. Honestly the SSJS version is much simpler, but depending on your use case, it may not be advisable.

AMPSCRIPT Example: ([ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/unsubEvent.htm))

```
%%[ SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @sid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
/* I usually recommend putting in something like "Unsub via Pref Center" here for reason */

/* You must set ClientID when working with On Your Behalf accounts
var @lue_oyb; 
set @lue_oyb = CreateObject('ClientID') 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_oyb, 'ID', @mid)
SetObjectProperty(@lue, 'Client', @lue_oyb)
*/

SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId) ]%%
```

SSJS Example:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");
var subObj = Subscriber.Init("SubKey");
var status = subObj.Unsubscribe();
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks Gortonington the example you gave for SSJS works very fine. You are the best, thanks.